# ScopeGuard dismiss

Tags: c++, scopeguard

My code needs scope guards, however do I have to manually `Dismiss()` all the scope guards on exit from a function normally? i.e.

```
void Deleter(MyClass* obj)
{
    delete obj;
}

MyClass* Func()
{
    MyClass* obj = new MyClass();
    ScopeGuard sg1 = MakeObjGuard(Deleter, obj);

    //More objects created. And more scope guards.

    sg1.Dismiss();
    //...Same for other guards
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: What is definition of ScopeGuard and MakeObjGuard?

Comment: You'd be better off with just a `std::auto_ptr<MyClass> obj(new MyClass); ... return obj.release();`

Answer (score 1):

You have to dismiss the guards for the objects you want to stay alive after the function. Otherwise they will each delete the object they are guarding.

Answer (score 0):

Given [this implementation](http://drdobbs.com/184403758) of ScopeGuard, then the answer is yes. The object deletion will happen in the destructor of the ScopeGuard, unless you disable it by calling the Dismiss method.

Comment: But if returning a pointer to one of the objects, **that** object should better not be deleted. Perhaps ok for the others though.